# Store value of native query with resultSetMapping in external properties files

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Default approach (in entity):

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "SomeName", classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = SomeClass.class, columns = {...}))
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "CurrEntity.getSomeSelect"), query = "...", resultSetMapping = "SomeName")
public class CurrEntity ...
```

It works correctly in JpaRepository with method `List<SomeClass> getSomeSelect()`

The query is very large and I want to move it to properties file. It's very simple task - just create default `classpath:/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties` or customize new path with `@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:new-name.properties")` and then I can remove @NamedNativeQuery from entity class and use method in JpaRepository.

But! Now I cannot set result mapping, which was in @NamedNativeQuery (resultSetMapping = "SomeName").

I tried to find a solution but did not find anything. Also I inspected spring-jpa-data and also did not find anything. May be another ways are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your queries in a file called orm.xml. This file must be in the META-INF directory of your class path:

In orm.xml you can do everything you can with the annotations. The XML nodes also have the same name but with - instead of camel case:

Find out more here: https://gerardnico.com/jpa/orm.xml